# How do I best render a UI model representation given realm.io real-time data update capability?

Tags: android, realm

This question revolves around identifying an optimal, performant best practice approach to visually showing a one-to-many relationships in a UI between two listview objects where items in the left listview as associated with many objects in the right listview, and backed by a realm.io data store.

The situation is that I have two lists of objects, and need the UI to allow the user to visually create a mapping between them. The two lists directly map to tables in Realm, the mapping would logically represent multi-selection of instances in list 2 being related to a single object in list 1.

For example, assume a list of Song objects ("Moonlight Sonata, Color My World, Welcome to the Jungle"), each of which may be associated with one or more instances of Genre objects ("Classical, Romantic Era, 1800's, Rock, 70's, Pop, 80's"). Assume the song table has thousands or tens of thousands of songs, and a Genre table that has hundreds or thousands of Genres.

In the UI, the user is presented with the list of songs on the left, and a list of genres on the right. The user clicks on a song, then is able to multi-select which genres on the right should be associated with that song.

This relationship must be stored - in realm I assume this is modeled within the Song table as a RealmList of genre objects.

The tricky part is how to quickly, in real time, update the Genre listview on the right to show "selections" when each song object on the left is selected. Which songs are "selected" visually would match what the user had previously selected.

Is there a best practice for this? I am trying to avoid an arraylist backing store for the listview on the right, and instead be able to operate directly on the data using a standard cursor, but since the selection state changes so rapidly perhaps this simply can't be performant?

Or perhaps this isn't a realm question at all, and is more a function of how the listview item object gets rendered based on whether the ID of the genre being rendered is contained in the current Song object?

Input welcome!

Comment: RealmList so `android`, right?

Comment: P.S. the `RealmResults<T>` returned by a RealmQuery is a *cursor* with a *list interface*

Comment: Yes - Android. I'm experimenting now with handling this all in the communication between the ListView and Adapter, so not touching the data model at all in the Genre object. So the fact the list is backed by a Realm object structure "shouldn't matter".

Answer (score 0):

Realm and especially `RealmResults` will lazy-load all data unlike most ORM's. This means it doesn't matter if you have 10 songs or 100.000. It will be just as performant.

In your case it sounds like probably want to model both ways (Since Java hasn't added support for Backlinks yet: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607) for easier change listeners:

```
public class Genre extends RealmObject {
  private String name;
  private List<Song> songs;
}

public class Song extends RealmObject {
  private String title;
  private List<Genre> genres;
  private boolean selected;
}
```

That way you just hookup your Genre View and your Song view independently.